# R dplyr::mutate_ and lubridate::parse_date_time Standard Evaluation not working together as expected

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I thought this was a bug in dplyr, but it could just be my own misunderstanding of Standard Evaluation. if anyone could help that would be great

Consider:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- frame_data( ~ start_date,
                    "07/15/2015 15:39", 
                    "07/15/2015 15:42")

df_NSE <- df %>% 
          mutate(response_date = parse_date_time(start_date, orders ="mdY hm"))
```

I would have thought that something like the following would be a standard-evaluation equivalent:

```
  var_name <- "start_date"

    df_SE_expected_to_work <- df %>% 
              mutate_(response_date = ~parse_date_time(var_name, orders ="mdY hm"))
```

but this just throws a warning and just has blank rows for the response_date column:

```
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

I tried many variations even with interp, just to make sure it wasnt my understanding of NSE such as this one:

```
df_SE_interp_expected_to_work <- df %>% 
          mutate_(response_date = interp(~parse_date_time(var_name, orders ="mdY hm"), var_name = var_name))
```

but i get the same outcome

I was able to hack a working solution for both cases:

```
df_SE_working <- df %>% 
          mutate_(response_date = ~parse_date_time(df[[var_name]], orders ="mdY hm"))
df_SE_interp_working <- df %>% 
          mutate_(response_date = interp(~parse_date_time(df[[var_name]], orders ="mdY hm"), var_name = var_name))
```

```r
sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] lazyeval_0.1.10.9000 lubridate_1.5.0      ednaetl_0.1          purrr_0.2.0          psqlfun_0.1         
 [6] dplyr_0.4.3.9000     tidyr_0.4.0          uuid_0.1-2           RPostgreSQL_0.4      DBI_0.3.1           

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.3        assertthat_0.1     R6_2.1.2           magrittr_1.5       stringi_1.0-1     
 [6] tools_3.2.3        stringr_1.0.0      yaml_2.1.13        parallel_3.2.3     rsconnect_0.4.1.11
[11] knitr_1.12.3
```

Maybe I'm just missing something obvious to make it work with mutate_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try just

```
df2 <- df %>%
    mutate_(response_date = ~parse_date_time(start_date, orders ="mdY hm"))
```

The use of formula notation is just a dodge to avoid R trying to evaluate the given expression. So you can use exactly the same call as in NSE, but with a squiggle tacked on.

---

To illustrate how to do this programmatically:

```
x <- "start_date"
df2 <- df %>%
    mutate_(response_date = formula(sprintf("~parse_date_time(%s, orders='mdY hm')", x)))
```

Comment: This wont work because im trying to use this programmatically, the goal is to use a variable(varname) that holds a string("start_date") that is a column in the dataframe df. Anyways wouldnt it just be easier to use the NSE version? or did you mean to use var_name instead of start_date in the codeblock above?

Comment: @Manny No, I meant to use start_date. And doing it this way lets you construct the formula using the standard methods.

Comment: @alistare Sorry i didnt see you updated your answer Hong ooi. I think the overall the cleanest and fastest solution might be to do it outside of the pipe. Thanks for helping with solutions and suggestions. I think Hong Ooi is technically what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Standard evaluation evaluates things (more or less) as they would be in base R, which means you can't use unquoted column names if you want to evaluate `var_name` as column name; instead you have to specify a data.frame you want to subset.

There's another issue here, though: a `tbl_df` does not return a vector when you subset to a column name, but rather a single column `tbl_df`, which `parse_date_time` can't handle.

For example,

```
> df[,var_name]
Source: local data frame [2 x 1]

        start_date
             (chr)
1 07/15/2015 15:39
2 07/15/2015 15:42

> dfdf <- as.data.frame(df)
> dfdf[,var_name]
[1] "07/15/2015 15:39" "07/15/2015 15:42"
```

which is likely a result of `dplyr`'s efforts to make *everything* it returns a dataframe. Thus

```
df %>% mutate_(response_date = ~parse_date_time(df[,var_name], orders ="mdY hm"))
```

will fail, but

```
dfdf <- as.data.frame(df)
dfdf %>% mutate_(response_date = ~parse_date_time(dfdf[,var_name], orders ="mdY hm"))
```

will work. You get it to work above by using `[[` subsetting, which returns a vector for both `tbl_df` and `data.frame`; another option would be to force the issue with `unlist`.

As far as I know, there's no way to call columns created in the course of a chain, or grouped columns (aside from nesting the grouping); overall, the SE options open some programming possibilities, but at the cost of convenience (plus a good amount of confusion).

Comment: Thanks this helped with my understanding of the underlying issues.  I have a couple of follow up questions,  if this is true: 
*... rather a single column tbl_df, which parse_date_time can't handle.*
why does the NSE version still return correctly, isnt it also a tbl_df?
Also, which workaround is the most efficient workaround?

Comment: When you pass the NSE version an unquoted column name, it internally subsets to a vector of the values in that column. `dplyr` is consistent about returning `tbl_df` or `tbl_dt` dataframes and taking dataframe-like objects, but internally it uses vectors for working with single variables, as that's what everything else uses.

Comment: As for what's most efficient, unless you're running many thousands of iterations of this code or your data is enormous, speed probably isn't an issue, so pick whichever will still make sense when you look at it in 6 months or so. If speed actually matters, staying with `tbl_df` is probably fastest, as you avoid conversions, but you'd have to benchmark to see.

Comment: This will likely blow up if you insert it into a pipeline of decent length, because it will use the _original_ value of `dfdf` rather than the one that's been processed through the pipeline.

Comment: @HongOoi Yeah. Do you know if there's a way to reference created variables within SE (aside from writing code as a string)? That's a fairly long-standing question I've had, actually.

Comment: @HongOoi Yeah, but that writes code as a string, which I try to avoid, if possible. Maybe with `substitute` and `quote`, but it seems like there's got to be a better way.

Comment: I'm missing something, but really I should probably ask my own question when I have a moment to make an appropriate MRE.

Comment: Hey alistaire i was trying to give you a plus one because you gave me a better understanding of why this problem was happening, but it didnt let me because my reputation is too low.